# Searching VSIs using operatingSystemReferenceCode

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am searching **VSIs** and **Bare Metal** to retrieve all devices with a specific **operatingSystemReferenceCode**.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?resultLimit=0,100&objectMask=mask[datacenter,status,globalIdentifier,primaryBackendIpAddress,billingItem.categoryCode,billingItem.description,billingItem.createDate,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.username,billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord.email,users.username,users.email,users.userStatus,operatingSystemReferenceCode,softwareComponents.passwords,operatingSystem,hourlyBillingFlag,localDiskFlag,managedResourceFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,powerState,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.name,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.id,blockDeviceTemplateGroup.blockDevices,blockDevices.diskImage,networkVlans,activeTransactionCount,activeTransactions,consoleIpAddressRecord.type,consoleIpAddressRecord.port,consoleIpAddressRecord.ipAddress.ipAddress]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"operatingSystemReferenceCode":{"operation":"^=REDHAT_6_64"}}}
```

This returns all devices and not just the VSIs with REDHAT_6_64 operatingSystemReferenceCode.

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The object filter only works with columns that exist in a specific table in the database(in this case case the table is VirtualGuest and the column is operatingSystemReferenceCode), otherwise it does not work. In this case the "operatingSystemReferenceCode" field must be an auto generated field when a request is executed, that is why the filter does not work.

So you need to look for a column which exist, you can try this filter to get all VSIs with  REDHAT

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"operatingSystem":{"softwareDescription" : {"manufacturer": {"operation":"Redhat"}}}}}
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you that worked. I was looking at the SoftLayer_Software_Description data type and found manufacturer so I saw reference code on this data type structure I replaced manufacturer in the objectFilter with referenceCode, but that didn't work. Is there a place to look that define tables and describes columns in the tables.

Comment: Nope, the only way is try with each column that you see. I know it is painful :(.

Comment: Wow, so the data type definitions in the documentation does NOT correspond to database tables and columns.

Comment: As I told you, some fields are autogenerated somehow programatically when you make a request, that's why the object filter does not work with those fields.